# Is there a tool designed for holding multiple electrical wires together to keep them in place for wire nut?

Tags: electrical

I am trying to wire three hot wires together with a pigtail which means I need to twist four 14-gage wires into a nut (I am using a tan nut which I believe is suitable for this).

The problem I'm having is holding them all steady so I can twist them together real good before capping them off.  Is there a tool designed for this?  It's a problem I've always had and it seems like someone would have come up with a solution.

Comment: Is the power on?  I thought we dealt with this issue a few years back.

Comment: You could try just using some electrical tape to hold them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. It's called [Lineman's Pliers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lineman's_pliers).

[image]

To use:

1. Strip the wires a bit longer than required (1" - 1 1/2").
2. Hold the wires at the insulation between your thumb and forefinger.
3. Pinch the tip of all the wires in the lineman's pliers.
4. Twist the wires together using the pliers.
5. Trim the end of the wires to the proper length.
6. Twist on the twist-on wire connector.

[image]

---

You could also try using crimp connectors, with insulated caps.

[image: Crimp Connector][image: Crimp Connector Insulator]

But then you'll need a crimp tool

[image: Crimp Tool]

---

Or as auujay points out, you can use push-in wire connectors. Which you can read about on [the blog](http://diy.blogoverflow.com/2012/01/tool-review-ideal-in-sure-push-in-wire-connectors/)

[image]

Comment: Personally I get too frustrated trying to cram a large number of wires into a nut (even a large one designed for it). I just use the multi-push in connectors for the few times I need to do this: http://diy.blogoverflow.com/2012/01/tool-review-ideal-in-sure-push-in-wire-connectors/

Comment: @auujay If you're "cramming" wires, you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Drill AWG # 10 holes in a solid thimble, and push 2 or 3 wires into the holes, and twist with the addition of wings on the thimble like a wing nut.  This would twist the wires together to get first a good mechanical connection prior to putting on a wire nut style connector.  The current goes through the wires and not the spring of the wire nut connector, so this mechanical "bonding" is what would be desired using a tool that is better to do the job than an electricians line mans pliers.

I saw one for sale at an electrical wholesalers outlet, but didn't remember to pick it up thinking I'd see it again.

Answer (score 0):

Three wires can be held nicely at 120 degrees from each other in three-jaw drill chuck.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest "tool" to twist the wires, is the wire nut.

Put the wires in the wire nut untwisted and as you twist the wire nut, the wires will naturally twist.

Answer (score 0):

I always hand twist the wires before inserting into the wire nut,the wire nut doesn't always twist the wires,therefore they can easily be pulled out.Of course some folks may not do this,however it seems to be a good thing.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).